# Visual Basic 6: how to make application visible in taskbar?

Tags: vb6

I've set property ShowInTaskBar to true, but my application is not visible in taskbar.
Form has minimize, maximize and close buttons. When I click minimize, form minimizes to a small form in the bottom left corner on the screen, but doesn't show up in the taskbar.

Comment: What type is your form? Sizable? Fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Is your form modal?

```
MyForm.Show vbModal
```

If so then you'll have to do something like [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Windows/Forcing_a_Window_to_Show_in_the_TaskBar/article.asp) to make it show in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I still work with VB6 on a daily basis.  I found this work around to make a form shown by MyForm.Show vbModal appear on the taskbar.

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Call ShowWindow(Me.hWnd, vbHide)
    Me.Caption = Me.Caption
    Call ShowWindow(Me.hWnd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat. How did you come up with it?

Comment: A late night Google search. :)